# React-Native "yarn ios" fails after XCode update

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I've got the problem after updating XCode to version 14.3 . Now i still get fail even i downgraded my Xcode version to 14.2 .

My React native version: 0.69.4

Error output:

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
        Ld /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-euysazkvmloamzahdviqkpvysca/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/myApp.app/myApp normal (in target 'myApp' from project 'myApp')
(1 failure)
```

i tried this solutions that didn't worked for me:

- deleting node_modules, yarn.lock and reinstall all with "yarn"
- deleting Pods, Podfile.lock, build files and reinstall with "yarn pod"
- deleting derivedData from ~Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
- tried this solution [github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/36739)

if you have a solution i would be appreciated.